# How to use Qt QColormap in code?

Tags: qt, c++11, qt5, qwidget

I want to achieve something like this .
 [image: Color chart]

I looked into the Qt QColormap but I did'nt get enough information to code it. If someone knows how to do this. Please share code snippet.

Comment: QColorMap is not a widget and does not serve to paint, it maps the colors referring to each hardware so that the painting is independent of the hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more question about color models then Qt really but basically you are trying to make a full circle around edge of [HSL color model](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/hsl/) while keeping saturation.

To produce something like that in Qt you will utilize gradient brush; since we want continuous blend I used [QLinearGradient](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlineargradient.html). If you look at the color wheel above you will notice that red color is at 0 degrees, green is at 120 degrees and blue is at 240 degrees. QLinearGradient works with range from 0-1 so this will transform to 0, 1/3, 2/3 respectively. We also need need to add final stop which will complete the gradient back to red color.

I added bit of alpha channel to keep the color tone down so you can experiment with that; final code will look something like this:

```
class ColorScale : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QWidget::QWidget;

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override {
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.setOpacity(0.9);
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing);
        QLinearGradient gradient(0, 0, 0, height());
        QGradientStops stops;
        stops << QGradientStop(0, Qt::red);
        stops << QGradientStop(1.0/3, Qt::blue);
        stops << QGradientStop(2.0/3, Qt::green);
        stops << QGradientStop(1, Qt::red);

        gradient.setStops(stops);

        painter.fillRect(rect(), gradient);
    }
};
```

And it produces this:

[image: Color scale]

You can add labels by calling [QPainter::drawText](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawText-9).

Comment: It works. But for the entire window. How do I add ColorScale to another class suppose MainWindow in a QFrame/ QWidget like the one in the image which you sent

Comment: You can read about how Qt widgets work here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/widgets-tutorial.html. The sample I gave you is already a widget so you can use it in your main window by passing QMainWindow pointer as parent, e.g. in constructor of your MainWindow:
   ColorScale *widget = new ColorScale(this);

Comment: I have a class suppose ColorScale which has this color map now I want to drop this class into another class suppose MainWindow.cpp in its own widget. Something like ui->widget->layout()->addWidget(new ColorScale()); How do I do that?

Comment: Hi, check e.g. here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-widgets-windowlayout-example.html and replace QLineEdit with ColorScale.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://pastebin.com/Hj0Gugf1. At any rate I feel that your original question was answered so please be so kind and accept the answer.

Comment: Worked for me . Thanks !